# Como modelar para firebase

Tags: nodejs, firebase, express, mongoose

Estoy creando un backend con express, nodejs y **FIREBASE**
Quiero saber como crear un método de ruta o como crear un modelo para haces push en firebase adecuadamente

actualmente mi método lo paso por el postman y me manda error
este es el método que quiero crear

```
save: function(req, res) {
        var proyecto = new modelo();


        db.ref('pryectos').push(proyecto);

        return res.status(200).send({
            proyecto: proyecto,
        });
    }
```

este es el modelo que cree con mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EsquemaProyecto = Schema({
    nombre: String,
    descripcion: String,
    categoria: String,
    fecha: String,
    herramientas: String,
    imagen: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Proyecto', EsquemaProyecto);
```

**cómo podría hacer o qué librería debería de usar en vez de mongoose para modelar para firebase?**

Comment: Hola, te recuerdo que [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) es un ODM exclusivo para MongoDB. La verdad no conozco ningún ODM para Fierbase, en todo caso, ya que tu aplicación es Backend ¿porqué usar Firebase? Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras, por que Firebase con Angular me ha dado muchos problemas, no he sabido integrarlo correctamente. Aun intentando con la librería "angularfire2". Me da muchos errores y sobre todo ahora que Firebase ha cambiado la configuración de su SDK en la que ya no porvee los mismos datos que la librería angularfire2 pide